# Sqoop import data from mysql, job does not start

Tags: linux, java, mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I am using using sqoop 1.4.7 with Hadoop multi node cluster.
I have a problem with sqoop import (sqoop list-tables and list-databases work fine). I have a Name Node and 2 data nodes in separate VM (ubuntu).

When I execute the sqoop import, it  stops at

> INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1559401109250_0003

and does not continue the process and nothing will be found in the HDFS!

PS:

1. I added the mysl-connector-java `bin.jar`!
2. I can add other files to my HDFS normally.

What can I do to fix this?